# Converted UWP applications do not work on Xbox One

Tags: windows, uwp, xbox, xbox-one, desktop-bridge

I have a UWP developers licence for Xbox One, and i'm trying to figure out how to convert existing Windows programs to UWP, and run them on my Xbox One in dev mode. I converted a program to UWP with Desktop App Converter, but I needed to manually edit the appxmanifest.xml to get it to install on my xbox one, and when launched, it redirects to the windows store.

Answer (score 7):

Win32 app that converted with desktop bridge can run only on Win10 PC. Other win10 families - Mobile, Xbox, etc - does not support the converted app.

Comment: I believe you, but is there doc somewhere mentioning this? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Please refer the table on the mid of following link, the row "Strength".You can find that the only the column "UWP"  have the description "Support for Xbox, HoloLens, IoT or Surface Hub". In fact, desktop bridge is just a mechanism to deploy the WPF/WinForms/Win32 apps via Microsoft Store, not a magic technology to convert it as UWP. And, yes, the documentation is poor, I agree. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/choose-your-platform#platform-comparison-uwp-wpf-and-windows-forms